# Kotlin coroutine concurrency and cached value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently trying to create a caching layer around a web request. So far I've written:

```
class Repository(private val webServices: WebServices) {
  private var cachedItems: List<Item>? = null

  suspend fun getItems(): List<Item> {
    cachedItems?.let { return it }

    val items = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { webServices.getItems() }
    cachedItems = items
    return items
  }
}
```

My concern is what will happen when `getItems()` is invoked by two callers simultaneously. Ideally, I'd only want one web request to occur. What's the recommended approach for dealing with this issue when using coroutines?

Comment: Hi! Do you want to use coroutines only for resolve this problem?

Comment: Yep! This is just an exercise in learning how to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple solution.

```
class Repository(private val webServices: WebServices) {
  private val cachedItems = async(Dispatchers.IO, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
    webServices.getItems()
  }

  suspend fun getItems(): List<Item> {
    return cachedItems.await()
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty neat! Will it avoid jumping to a different dispatcher on subsequent calls?

Comment: Yes it will. Subsequent calls would just be a simple read, no dispatchers will be involved.

Comment: Nice one. If the request fails, will it propagate an exception? Will it re-attempt the web request on subsequent calls?

Comment: It will propagate the exception. The exception will also be cached as a result. So everytime the method is called, the same exception will be thrown. If you want to retry the request, you'll need a different construct other that `async`. Probably best to use a caching library if these details matter.

Answer (score 2):

First of all what I think you should do is to just use a cache library, like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). It is generally not recommended to reinvent the wheel especially with caching which has *a lot* of moving parts. I wouldn't recommend `lazy` either if you want a **cache** since `lazy` does not support cache eviction and similar things.

As for coroutines what you want to do is a single threaded dispatcher which you can produce from a Java `Executor` like this: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()`. You can also use `actor`s for this purpose to get the same result.

If you want to learn how coroutines work in general I'd recommend [this article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html) by the Kotlin devs and also Roman Elizarov's [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8) on the topic!

Comment: I guess I should have clarified, but I'm looking for a way to do this without any external dependencies.

`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` is definitely one approach, but I'm wondering if there's something more elegant.

As for Roman's talk; yeah, it was great. I was in the audience :)

Comment: Why do you need something more elegant? Just to be elegant, or to serve a purpose? Also, why do you want to solve this without external dependencies? Is it part of your core business to write cache solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for your case:

```
class Repository(private val webServices: WebServices) {
    private val mutex = Mutex()

    private val items = mutableListOf<String>()

    suspend fun getItems(): List<String> {
        if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
            return items
        }

        if (!mutex.isLocked) {
            mutex.lock()
            val newItems = webServices.getItems()
            items.clear()
            items.addAll(newItems)
            mutex.unlock()
        } else {
            // not beauty code, it's still open question for me - how to improve it
            mutex.lock()
            mutex.unlock()
        }
        return items
    }
}
```

There is useful [article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html) about coroutines and concurrency. And this is [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/index.html) for `Mutex` class

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how this interacts with coroutines.  But in normal coding:

This is always a problem with lazy fetching.  The two main approaches I'm aware of are either for the call to use some form of synchronisation, or to risk multiple fetches as the penalty for avoiding blocking (as in your example).

The former case is more complex to write, but it needn't always synchronise; you could check for a cached value, and if found use it; else you could gain the lock and check *again*, only fetching the value if it's still not present.  That double-checked locking is tricky to get right, but once the value has been fetched, published, and stale cache values expired, it shouldn't need to use the lock any more.

But instead of writing that yourself, Kotlin has done it for you — you could simply declare the property as delegated [by lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy), and let the stdlib do all the hard work!  It even lets you specify which thread-safety mode to use.

Answer (score -1):

The most simplistic way would be do use `lazy` which is synchronised under the covers like so:

```
class Repository(private val webServices: WebServices) {
  private val cachedItems by lazy { webServices.getItems() }

  suspend fun getItems(): List<Item> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { cachedItems }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't call suspend functions from lazy initializer